# Why can a select statement acquire more than 1 Sch-S lock on one table?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, sql-server-2017

I have a repeating deadlock in my production environment. I cannot reproduce it in staging.

Script 1 is a scheduled data import procedure.

```
-- Create and populate new_TableImported

if object_id('old_TableImported') is not null drop table old_TableImported
set transaction isolation level serializable;
set xact_abort on;
begin try
    begin tran
        if object_id('TableImported') is not null exec sp_rename 'TableImported', 'old_TableImported'
        exec sp_rename 'new_TableImported', 'TableImported'
    commit
end try
begin catch
    if (xact_state() <> 0) rollback tran;
    throw;
end catch
set transaction isolation level read committed;
if object_id('old_TableImported') is not null drop table old_TableImported
```

Script 2 is a scheduled data export procedure: just select from a view.

```
CREATE VIEW [export].[vSomeDataNeededOutside]
AS
select
    t.*,
    e.SomeField
from dbo.OneOfMyTables t
    left join (
        select ...
        from TableImported
        group by ...
    ) e on ...
where ...
```

According to data collected with SQL Server Profiler.

1. Select (2) starts. `Sch-S` lock is obtained on `TableImported`.
2. Data import (1) runs up to `sp_rename` block. `Sch-M` lock is requested, and the query waits.
3. (2) for some reason requests additional `Sch-S` lock on `TableImported`.
4. Deadlock. (1) waits (2) to release the first `Sch-S` lock, (2) waits (1) to acquire the second `Sch-S` lock.

What is going on? Why do select try to obtain the second lock of the same type on the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is creating more than one lock because your derived table is getting executed more than once.

*Why* the sub-query is being executed more than once is another issue?

Check your execution plan.   its quite possible the Estimated Number of **executions** on `TableImported`  matches closely to the Estimated Number of **rows** for `OneOfMyTables`
There is some discussion around this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486512/inner-join-with-derived-table-using-sub-query)

If you *could* change the the left join to an inner join, it would only scan (or seek) `TableImported` once.

As for the difference between Staging and prod... or a solution ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  (sorry)

Comment: If I manually execute (2) and watch actual execution plan, it shows one execution of subquery and merge join with `OneOfMyTables`. I understand that sometimes optimizer can decide to perform nested loops. But sounds very strange: does SQL Server really request new `Sch-S` for each loop without releasing the previous one? So, if there are (for example) 20000 nested loops, 20000 `Sch-S` are being aquired simultaneously?